# onclick='check(); return false' in html causes flask_wtf to fetch none value from the form

Tags: javascript, html, flask, flask-wtforms

This is a part of code on which I am working. Here,the amount variable is getting the value from python flask

```
function check() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The value of your 
salary is {{amount}}"; }
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" 
 onclick='check(); return false'>
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the onclick event hook up? Could you provide the html element?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use flask's interpolation on the client, it won't work that way. You'll need to use JavaScript to access whatever `amount` is if you're not submitting the form for flask to process.

Answer (score 1):

Added this condition

{% if amount %} The value of your salary is {{amount}} {% endif %}

and worked like a charm